# I am building a portfolio website using React and Sanity but I am running into a CORS policy error when fetching for data from Sanity

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a portfolio website with React and Sanity but I am running into a CORS policy issue when fetching data from Sanity. This is the error......

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://6kyh9tpo.apicdn.sanity.io/v2022-10-26/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type%20%3D%3D%20%22abouts%22%5D' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

I have tried to solve it and looked for solutions all over with zero success. Your help will be very much appreciated...

The connection

Here is the code ...

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

import './About.scss';
import images from '../../constants/images'
import { urlFor, client } from '../../client';

const About = () => {
  const [abouts, setAbouts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const query = '*[_type == "abouts"]';

    client.fetch(query)
    .then((data)=> { setAbouts(data)})
      .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <h2 className="head-text">I Know That <span>Good Development</span> makes <span>Good Business</span>
      </h2>

      <div className="app__profiles">
        {abouts.map((about, index) => (
          <motion.div
            whileInView={{ opacity: 1 }}
            whileHover={{ scale: 1.1 }}
            transition={{ duration: .5, type: 'tween' }}
            className='app__profile-item'
            key={`${about.title} + ${index}`}
          >
            <img src={urlFor(about.imgUrl)} alt={about.title} />
            <h2 className="bold-text" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>{about.title}</h2>
            <p className="p-text" style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>{ about.description}</p>
          </motion.div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default About
```

Answer (score -1):

just downloads the Cors Unblock Chrome Extension it will help you

Comment: Nice suggestion, but this should be a comment.

Comment: Well I tried that but It didn't work.....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).